# Terminal being killed by lightdm stop

Tags: 16.04, command-line, lightdm, cuda

I am trying to install cuda-9.0 for my machine. So, I followed the following steps:

1. Open a terminal using Alt+Ctrl+F1
2. Log in using my credentials
3. Run `sudo lightdm stop` to kill X

After this I lost my terminal session and fell back to my GUI instead! Also I don't have the ability to switch to a terminal using either Alt+Ctrl+F1-F6.

Is there a reasonable explanation for that? It seems that my terminal was GUI based (how is that possible anyway?) and got killed but my actual GUI had different pid and did not?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you're using 16.04, then you should probably be using the systemd command `sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service` or (perhaps better) `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target`

Comment: I don't get it. This will work on my terminal? And why is terminal being killed?

Comment: My *guess* is that `sudo lightdm stop` actually *starts* a new instance of `lightdm`